# ios - MapKit print annotation to map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I am trying to place a custom annotation on a map at coordinates taken from an NSArray using mapKit. The annotation does not appear when I run the app though. I have checked using NSLog, that both latitude and longitude are present.

I'm not sure where it is going wrong. There is another method in the class that prints an annotation successfully using the devices location, the difference is in this method I want to use a custom location with CLLocationCoordinate2D.

This is the method from the .m file:

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize mapView=_mapView;


- (void)place:(NSArray *)tweetData
{
    NSArray *array = tweetData;

    NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:0];


    NSString *lat = [dict objectForKey:@"lat"];
    NSString *lon = [dict objectForKey:@"lon"];

    double lat2 = [lat doubleValue];
    double lon2 = [lon doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"String %@, %@", lat, lon);
    NSLog(@"Double %.8f, %.8f", lat2, lon2);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat2, lon2);

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = position;
    annotation.title = @"working";
    annotation.subtitle = @"working";

    [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];    
}
```

Update: Just to clarify this other method in the same class works fine. I just want to use a different location that I've taken from the array. The default annotation is fine I just want to change the location.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"Where am I?";
    point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```

Update 2: This is the other class which contains the call to `place:`

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@implementation ViewController

@synthesize button=_button;
@synthesize label=_label;
@synthesize tweetId=_tweetId;
@synthesize tweetContent=_tweetContent;
@synthesize connection=_connection;
@synthesize mapView=_mapView;

NSString *tweet;
NSMutableArray *locationArray;

- (IBAction)fetchTweet
{

    NSString *sendCo = [[locationArray valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"sendCo: %@", sendCo);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/Jersey/rest/hello"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[sendCo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];

    tweet = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[tweet dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                        options:0 error:NULL];


    NSLog(@"%@", jsonData);

    _mapView = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
    [_mapView place:jsonData];

}
```

Comment: Did you implement `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol on your `MapViewController` class?

Comment: Instead of posting a duplicate question of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740530/ios-annotation-not-being-placed-on-map), you should edit that question with more details.  For example, what does the "other method in the class" look like?  Do you want to show a custom image or just a default pin?

Comment: @Anna I have updated the question to show the other working method.

Comment: What _exactly_ do the NSLogs print out?

Comment: @Anna The NSLogs print `2014-03-30 23:10:33.603 REST[757:70b] String 45.38365782, -5.2731979
2014-03-30 23:10:33.604 REST[757:70b] Double 45.38365782, -5.2731979`

Comment: Where are you expecting that annotation to appear?  Those coordinates are in the Atlantic Ocean off the west coast of France.

Comment: @Anna Shouldn't the annotation appear wherever the coordinates are though.

Comment: Yes but my point is: Is that where you are looking for that annotation?  If that's where you're looking but it's not there, the simplest other possibility is that _mapView is nil.  Right before the addAnnotation line in the `place:` method, add this NSLog and see what it says: `NSLog(@"_mapView = %@", _mapView);`.

Comment: The other possibility is that you have not implemented viewForAnnotation correctly.  You don't _have_ to implement viewForAnnotation to show annotations.  But if you _do_, it must be done right or the annotation might not appear.  If you've implemented it, add that code to the question.

Comment: @Anna I added the NSLog which says the mapview is null. How do I change that.

Comment: That's the problem (_mapView is null).  Now you have to find out why it's null.  Where is the `place:` method called from?  It's possible that you're calling the `place:` method before the xib/storyboard controls have been initialized.

Comment: @Anna I've updated the question with the other class that calls `place:`

Comment: @user3461851: In ViewController, where do you actually present (show) MapViewController?  In the fetchTweet method, the problem is that you are creating a new instance of MapViewController and calling place: _before_ presenting it.  That's why _mapView is null in MapViewController (because the UI controls are initialized when the view is actually presented).  If MapViewController is already showing when fetchTweet is called, then maybe you just need to call `[_mapView place:jsonData];` (don't alloc+init it again).

Comment: @Anna I removed the `_mapView = [[MapViewController alloc] init];` but it didn't seem to have any effect on placing an annotation.

Answer (score 1):

As igor says, you should implement *MKMapViewDelegate* protocol, set your controller as the MKMapView delegate and implement at least the next method:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    static NSString* PinReuseIdentifier = @"YourReuseIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: PinReuseIdentifier];
    if (!annotationView){
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier: PinReuseIdentifier];
    }
    //Customize annotationView

    return annotationView;
}
```

And provide your custom pin view inside *MKAnnotationView*

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, what exactly will this do though. What is the purpose of the PinReuseIdentifier.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: and this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKAnnotationView/initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:

Comment: You do _not_ need to implement the viewForAnnotation delegate method (or any delegate methods) to show _default_ annotations.  In addition, the sample code does not handle view re-use correctly and if you want to provide a "custom pin view", you should create a plain MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView.

Comment: It's better to find out what the real problem is (_mapView is null) rather than make assumptions and direct the OP in the wrong direction.  Linking to the docs by itself doesn't really help here either.